# error message displays at wrong place

Tags: html, css

Here is my [login](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mksxjvhg/1/), when the username or mail is wrong the error message is shown, but it is displayed next to email label(the red part "Ei"). I want to show message beneath the boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.message--red {
  clear: both;
  color: #ed1b2e;
}
```

but keep in mind i have no idea where you want to place your message nad it is not specified in the question

Answer (score 1):

your question is vague, I know that your error message is dislocated, but I don't know where you want it to be, so assuming that you want it beneath your boxes, here's the `link`:

[Error Message](https://jsfiddle.net/mksxjvhg/2/)